# Forcing WSARecv to overlap

Tags: c++, winapi, overlap, winsock2, io-completion-ports

I'm triying to implement a server which uses IOCompletionPort to read from its clients.
I have something very similar to [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13382/A-simple-application-using-I-O-Completion-Ports-an).

If I understand correctly, this should be my design:

1. [Main Thread] Create a listen socket, bind and listen
2. [Main Thread] Create an event and attach it to the socket accept signal using WSAEventSelect
3. [Accept Thread] Wait for the event and accept a client
4. [Accept Thread] When a client connects, use CreateIOCompletionPort to use the IOCompletion queue with it
5. [Accept Thread] The accept thread calls the first WSARecv with overlap parameters
6. [Worker Threads] Use the queue to implement a leader-follower pattern on WSARecv

After some reading on WSARecv ([Here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I discovered that WSARecv might return immediately with the data if the data is ready. That seems kinda weird because that means that a worker could loop on WSARecv without returning to the IO queue if the client sends fast enough - And that could cause client starvation...

Hereby my questions are:

1. Is there a way to "force" WSARecv to not returning immediately? I mean, to return IO_PENDING 100% of the time?
2. If not - What would be the correct design, optimized for scalability?

This is how I use WSARecv:

```
flags = 0;
receiveResult = WSARecv(clientSocket, &(olStruct->Buffer), 1, &bytesReceived, &flags, (OVERLAPPED*)olStruct, NULL);
```

olStruct is an extension for the OVERLAPPED struct.

<strike>EDIT:
I ended up reposting what I got from WSARecv using PostQueuedCompletionStatus. I'd love to hear other solutions though</strike>
See Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when WSARecv completes immediately it returns the buffer AND posts to the IOCompletionPort queue.

So the current design still stands.

Answer (score 1):

If you have associated your handle with a completion port, `WSARecv()` returning immediately with success is semantically equivalent for you to `WSARecv()` returning with pending, **unless** you have:

- set completion port bypass on success, as described in [SetFileCompletionNotificationModes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365538(v=vs.85).aspx), or
- you are providing a valid HANDLE with a bit set, as described in [GetQueuedCompletionStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986(v=vs.85).aspx) for hEvent member